# How to cumulatively add transformations (6DoF)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations, angle, robotics

I am stuck with a time-series problem of estimating 6DOF. 
I will use a simple example to explain what I need. 
Suppose there are 4 points about an origin **o** in 3D space i.e. $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$.

I will use $T_{ab}$ to denote transformation of $A$ to $B$ and so on.

$T_{ab}$ is a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$ of rotation + translation.

1. Say I start at $A$ (which is the init point and all successive transformation is with respect to $A$) and move to $B$, hence I can get the transformation
   $T_{ab}$.
2. Then I move from $B$ to $C$, but my algorithm will provide the transformation $T_{ac}$

Therefore:  $T_{bc}$ = $T_{ac}$ * $(T_{ab})^{-1}$ ........ (eq.1)

The problem is if I update or reset my algorithm at $C$ it will move back to $A$. So the transformation using eq. 1 will be incorrect once the algorithm updates itself. That is if I move from $C$ to $D$, the transformation will be now begin from $A$ instead of $C$ since the update resets the init point (I cant change this behavior as its important for some other purposes).

What I have done:
I kept track (multiple) of all intermediate transformations given my equation 1 above but it seems not be be working.

What is one way I can keep the transformation correct mathematically even after the program resets.

Comment: what you mean by update/reset algorithm? Do you do this updation inside an iteration?or when do you or the algorithm updates itself? Not clear to me!

Comment: The reset/update is done when the  confidence level of tracking the trajectory is low. It resets to known model which is provided in prior if the confidence is low or updates if the confidence of tracking is high.

Answer (score 1):

To back out a transformation, you apply the inverses of the transformations in reverse order.

So if you have three transformations, each consisting of a rotation and a translation:

$$T_{3t}T_{3r}T_{2t}T_{2r}T_{1t}T_{1r}\vec{v} = \vec{v}_t$$

Then to get $\vec{v}$ again you do this:

$$T_{1r}^{-1}T_{1t}^{-1}T_{2r}^{-1}T_{2t}^{-1}T_{3r}^{-1}T_{3t}^{-1}\vec{v}_t = \vec{v}.$$

I think it's just a matter of keeping track of how you transform the vector and then just unrolling it to get back to the start.

Comment: Actually your approach does gives the solution thanks.. But only issue is inverse with is not problem is computational cost is not limited. Thanks alot